# Eclipse CDT Including Unreferenced Files in Automatically Generated Build

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm new to cpp in eclipse and trying to mess with simple builds.  I have made a basic project which automatically generates build info (no user-defined makefile).

### Simple (Working) Case

I made a "Hello World" project called Test (not an empty project).  It has one file - Test.cpp with a main() in => builds and runs fine.

Test.cpp

```
int main() {
  // output some stuff
}
```

### Slightly More Complex (Working) Case

I make a new file called Main.cpp.  Move the main() function into Main.cpp and make a decleration of a function in main too - void test();

The test() function lives in Test.cpp, which is where I provide the function definition.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 

void test();

int main() {
  // Use test() 
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 

void test() {
  // output some stuff
}
```

Build it, there are now two .o files in the Debug directory - Test.o and Main.o.  This runs fine.

### The Problem

Now I try to introduce a third file - Limits.cpp.

Limits.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 

void printLimits() {
  // Print out limits for different integer sizes
}
```

Again I provide a deceleration of this function in Main.cpp.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 

void test();

void printLimits();

int main() {
  // Use printLimits() 
}
```

This time there is no object file created for Limits in the Debug folder => the build fails.

```
Main.cpp:*line* undefined reference to `getLimits()'
```

It just looks like the autogenerated build config for the project is duff.  I've tried looking around the project properties but I have had no luck.  I've tried including the path/file in Include Paths/Include files, other objects, and I've checked just about every other property I can see.  This has been frustrating me for two days.

The strange thing about this is case 2.  It looks like because Test.cpp was the first file made it always includes this in the build? (even if it is not imported).  Where as because Limits.cpp is new and not imported it doesn't generate an object file so it can't link the function.

I could me making an error by needing to include the files but my understanding is if all the object files make it to the linker then all will be well (ie I just need the function declarations when making the object files which is what I have here).

With a "Blank project" it seems to compile all the cpp files even if they are never used so my case above works. (Although, it doesn't work for files in subfolders of src). Looks like its a "feature" of the "Hello world" project type but it's going to drive me crazy knowing there must be a way to get it to do this.

If anyone knows if it is possible to include this file without writing my own makefile (I'm not a makefile guru (yet!)), or let me know if this is not possible with autogen CDT that would be great.

Using MinGW GCC toolchain.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/a/42402476/2796832 but it is impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the link - really helped point me in the right direction.  For some reason it was showing the header file logo when the file had no extension - D'oh.  Adding the extension seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Great. Happy to hear it helped :-)